# How to solve this nonlinear 3 by 3 system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

So I have to solve this nonlinear system of equations with 3 equations and 3 unknowns.
The system is:
$$\begin{cases}
2A+3B-1=2CA \\
2B+2BC=-3A\\
 B^{2}+A^{2}=-1
\end{cases}$$

No methods that I'm familiar with seem to help me solve this and I haven't come to the right idea in like 3 hours.

Comment: Hello @cnymfais, welcome to MSE. Your question will be much better received if you note down the directions that you have tried, even if they yield no results.

Comment: By the way, from the last condition, I assume that $A,B,C$ are not real numbers?, If so, you should also specify that

Comment: you could eliminate $C$ first, then eliminate $B$ and arrive at a quartic equation in $A$

Answer (score 1):

Elimination of the variables $A$ and $C$ yields
\begin{align*}
C & =\frac{ - 16B^3 + 48B^2 - 17B + 21}{24},\\
A & =\frac{ - 16B^3 - 17B - 3}{12},
\end{align*}
satisfying the
quartic equation (here in $B$) is $$16B^4 + 17B^2 + 6B + 9=0.$$ It has four solutions over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: I can't see how you eliminated C, could you explain it a bit further?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the first by $B$ and the second by $A$ and eliminate $ABC$. You obtain a conic in $A,B$:

$$3A^2+4AB+3B^2-B=0$$

which simplifies to

$$4AB-B-3=0.$$

Then squaring,

$$16A^2B^2=-16(B^2+1)B^2=(B+3)^2,$$ which is a nasty quartic.

Note: if you deduce $A$ from $B$ using the before last equation, no extra root is introduced by the squaring.